# Proof that $ \log_2(n^2+n) = \Omega(\log_2(n)) $

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

### Problem

Proof that $ \log_2(n^2+n) = \Omega(\log_2(n)) $

### Attempt to proof

$ \log_2(n^2+n) = \Omega(\log_2(n)) $ hold when $\exists(c,n_0)$ for which (by definition)
$$ \log_2(n) \ge c\log_2(n^2+n), \text{ when } n \ge n_0 $$
let $c=0, n_0=1$
$$ \implies \log_2(n) \ge 0, \text{ when } n \ge 1$$
Which holds for $\forall n$.

---

Is my proof correct?

Comment: No. (A) the inequality is the wrong way. (B) the constant $c$ must be positive

Comment: I think $\Omega$ requires $c>0.$ Otherwise $f(x)=\Omega(g(x))$ for any $f(x)>0$ and any $g(x).$ You need to find $c>0,n_0$ so that $\log_2(n)\leq c\log_2(n^2+n)$ for n\\geq n_0.$

Comment: There are two definitions in Wikipedia for $\Omega,$ and I think you want the version where $f(x)=\Omega(g(x))$ is equivalent to $g(x)=O(f(x)).$

Comment: Wich $c=0$, you could prove anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log(n^2+n)>\log(n^2)=2\log(n).$$